# Does $jR$ tell us anything about whether or not $j$ is a zero divisor?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring with unity. Then $u \in R$ is a unit iff the ideal $uR$ is as large as possible, namely $uR=R$. What I'd like to know is whether or not there's something analogous for zero divisors; something like "$j \in R$ is a zero divisor iff $jR$ is small enough that..."

Comment: $u$ is a unit if and only if the map $r\mapsto ur$ is surjective; $j$ is a zero divisor if and only if the map $r\mapsto jr$ is not injective. So it's more a question of kernel, rather than image.

Comment: @egreg, right, good point. In other words, we should be looking at $\mathrm{Ann}(j)$ rather than $jR$, in which case its trivial; $j$ is a zero-divisor iff $\mathrm{Ann}(j)$ has a non-zero element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following egreg's comment: "$j \in R$ is a zero divisor iff $jR$ is small enough that $\mathrm{Ann}(jR)$ contains a non-zero element." Too bad this is kind of trivial, though.